# How to configure the Vote entity model to have a composite PK?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

For the sake of simplicity, let's consider a simple scenario that mimics StackOverflow's question.

- Each user can post zero or more questions.
- Each question can have zero or more votes.
- Each user can optionally vote only once per question.
- For the sake of simplicity, let user who posts a question vote his/her own question. This feature will be removed later.

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Question> Questions { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Vote> Votes { get; set; }
}

public class Question
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public User User { get; set; } // the user to whom the question belongs
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Vote> Votes { get; set; }
}


public class Vote
{
    public bool IsUp { get; set; } // true = upvote or false = downvote

    public User User { get; set; }// the user who votes a question
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public Question Post { get; set; }// the question for which this vote is intended
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
}
```

## Question

How to make sure that there is no user who votes the same question twice or more? I am a newbie! If my entity models are too bad practically, any suggestion or improvement are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to put them in the column order,  SQL Server will then map it
Here's an example

```
public class Vote
{
  [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
  public string UserID { get; set; }

  [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
  public int QuestionID { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: While this is a valid approach for EF6, it's not applicable for EF Core.